# How to hide folder path from URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to hide the folder path from URL:

my URL :

```
mysitename/category/3590474628.html
mysitename/product/details/25038.html
```

I am trying to make a short URL like this:

```
mysitename/3590474628.html
mysitename/25038.html
```

here is my currently using .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?rt=$1&opt2=$2&opt3=$3&opt4=$4 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?rt=$1&opt2=$2&opt3=$3 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)\.html$ index.php?rt=$1&opt2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?rt=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to hit `mysitename/product/details/25038.html` in browser and change url to `mysitename/25038.html`?

Comment: What you ask is not possible in a general manner. Your rewriting engine needs to be able to distinguish between two cases: categories and product details. But from just a numeric file name this cannot be concluded. And your rewriting engine cannot somehow magically guess that. So you need to add something to the desired URLs which allows for a way to distinguish. Except if you can name a rule by which the engine could conclude from a number to whether a category or a product detail is requested.

Comment: If possible then yes.... plz